# Set aws elastic benastalk dynamic environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, apache-kafka, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Hi all now my spring boot app is running on aws eb docker platform, I want to set the dirfferent kafka consumer group id when creating a new instance by aws auto scaling(horizonal scaling).Is it possible? eg: like that
instance one's kafka consumer group id = my-consume-group-1 ,
instance two's kafka consumer group id = my-consume-group-2,

because I need to create different consumer group id for kafka

I trying wit many ways but can't find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, scaling of one app should be the same group. Then it'll read the same topics in parallel. Also with that approach, you shouldn't automatically scale based on CPU or memory, for example, because Kafka consumers can only scale up to the topic partitions amount. You should scale on consumer lag, instead (which would be a custom metric you need to expose from the app).

If you don't care about parallel consumption, then you can use a random UUID rather than needing anything specific to Beanstalk variables.

Comment: In my case, I need to consume one topic for both two instances (eg : when producer  produces a topic "hello" , I need to consume both instance but currently only one instance can consume because of same consume group id)

Comment: Like I said, use UUID class random method for your consumer config. Then all instances will always consume the data (until they restart, in which case, it'll process the same records again). If you need to track offsets per instance, then you should probably make separate beanstalk apps and use CloudFormation or Terraform to manage each. Then you can pass group id though as an environment variable

Comment: Thanks for your advice,it is helping me, now I can set the different consumer group id with the ec2 instance id in the java code.

Comment: If the EC2 instances aren't ephemeral, then that'd work as well